# how to find $n| 3^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

this  a problem in:
**Waclaw Sierpinski 250 problems in elementary number theory  1971**

if $n\in \Bbb N , n \gt1$ ,how to find :
$$n\mid3^n+1$$
the solution of book is :
There is only one such odd number $n$, namely $n = 1$. In fact, suppose
that there exists an odd number $n > 1$ such that $n\mid3^n+1$. Thus we have
$n\mid9^n— 1$. Let $n$ be a least positive integer $> 1$ such that $n\mid9^n— 1$.

**In view of $n\mid9^{\phi(n)}—1$, for $d=(n,\phi(n)) $  we shall have $n\mid9^d-1$**
.

Moreover, $d>1$
since if $d$ were equal to $1$, we would have $n\mid8$ which is impossible since $n$
is odd. Thus $1 < d\le \phi(n) < n$  ,   and $  d\mid n\mid 9^d— 1  $  , contrary to the definition
of the number $n$. Thus there is no odd number $n > 1$ such that $n\midЗ^n+1$.

in bold text, why right? $n$ is odd but it may $\gcd(n,9)\not = 1$ in fact from
odd number $n > 1$ such that $n\mid3^n+1$ we have $n\nmid9$ and it is used from $phi-Euler$ theorem.

Comment: To get a *divides* in LaTeX use `\mid`: compare `x|y` which gives $x|y$, to `x\mid y` which gives $x\mid y$. (If you want *not divides*, then the command is `\nmid`.

Comment: Any divisor of $3^n+1$ cannot be divisible by $3$, so is relatively prime to $9$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805712/find-all-odd-n-in-mathbbz-such-that-n-mid-3n1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$9^n-1 = (9^d-1)(9^{n-d}+9^{n-2d}+...+1)\\
9^{\phi(n)}-1 = (9^d-1)(9^{\phi(n)-d}+9^{\phi(n)-2d}+...+1)$$
$a=(n-d)$ and $b=(\phi(n) - d)$ are coprime. We can use the lemma that $$\gcd\left( \sum\limits_{i=0}^{a}c^i,~~\sum\limits_{i=0}^{b}c^i\right)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\gcd(a,b)}c^i$$

I don't know, this lemma can be a case of some famous theorem or something, but I invented it just now and therefore should prove. The proof is pretty intuitive: if we will search for this $\gcd$ with Euclid algorithm, it will be equal to searching the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$ with Euclid algorithm in the upper limits of sums. I think, it is too easy to explain it in detail.

Using this lemma we get $\gcd(9^x-1,9^y-1) = (9^{\gcd(x,y)}-1) = (9^d-1)$ in your case.