# Determine all integers $n>1$ such that $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Determine all integers $n>1$ such that $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer.

**Attempt:**

Notice that $n$ must be odd. And $n=3$ satisfies the condition. The number that we want must therefore satisfy

$$ 2^{n} \equiv (-1) \bmod (n^{2})$$

or

$$ 2^{n} = \alpha n^{2}-1 = (\sqrt{\alpha} n -1)(\sqrt{\alpha}n+1).$$

Notice that $\sqrt{\alpha}$ must be odd.

Comment: It is IMO 1990/3. More details can be found here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669194/a-solution-using-lifting-the-exponent-lemma-to-imo-1990-p3. Solution on kalva - https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln903.html

Comment: Note that since $n$ must be odd, $3\mid (2^n+1)$, hence $3\mid n$

Comment: @KeithBackman That is not true.

Comment: if $n$ is prime then $2^n+1\equiv3\pmod n$, so $n \nmid 2^n+1$ unless $n=3$

Comment: $(2^p)^q \equiv 2^q\bmod p$ via fermat . For p and q divisors multiplying to $n$.