# Proof Verification: Find all positive integer $n$ for which $n^2|2^n+1.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Find all positive integer $n$ for which $n^2|2^n+1.$

Proof:

- Note that $n$ is odd.
- Clearly $n=1$ satisfies. Then let $n>1.$ Consider any prime $p|n.$
- So we have $p|2^{2p\alpha}-1\implies ord_p(2)=2p\alpha~~\text{or}~~ 2.$ [we know that $ord_p(2)=k$ doesn't divide $n$ because if it did, then $2^n\equiv 1 \mod p.$ But we have $2^n\equiv -1 \mod p.$ And we have $n$ is odd. ]
- If $ord_p(2)=2p\alpha \implies 2p\alpha|p-1$ not possible because $2p\alpha > p-1.$
- Hence $ord_p(2)=2$ for all $p|n.$
- So $n|2^2-1\implies n=3.$ Clearly $n=3\implies 9|2^3+1$ satisfies.

So the only two solutions I got are $n=1,3.$

This question is actually an IMO 1990 P3 problem, so I think my solution is too simple for it. Can anyone verify? Thank you.

Comment: You have $ord_p(2) | \frac{2n}{p}$.  How do you propose getting to $ord_p(2) = 2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A solution using 'Lifting the exponent' lemma to IMO 1990 P3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669194/a-solution-using-lifting-the-exponent-lemma-to-imo-1990-p3). This other question and answer verifies that $n = 3$ is the only other solution, but as Brian's comment indicates, you haven't really explained, from that $\operatorname{ord}_p(2) \mid \frac{2n}{p}$, how you got to $\operatorname{ord}_p(2) = 2$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring   we know that $ord_p(2)=k$ doesn't divide $n$ because if it did, then $2^n\equiv 1 \mod p.$ But we have $2^n\equiv -1 \mod p.$

So order is $2p\alpha $ or $2.$ We have $n$ odd.

Comment: @SunainaPati As your comment indicates, $\operatorname{ord}_p(2)=k$ must be even. However, although $k$ can't have a prime factor of $p$, it may possibly contain different odd prime factors of n, and still be less than $\frac{2n}{p}$. Nonetheless, you can basically use your argument to prove the *smallest* prime factor of $n$ must be $3$.

Comment: This hasn't been tagged as proof-verification, despite it looking like it is the case.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Okay yes, I realised I made a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell what do we mean by $ord$?

Comment: @user69608 https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/ORPR/ORPR.pdf

Comment: @SunainaPati You're welcome. FYI, I wrote this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4258939/602049) to the proposed duplicate based somewhat on what you did, along with using the concepts of dealing with the smallest prime factors of $n$, that the multiplicative order must divide [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) of the prime, and the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma (LTE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma).